# trying to pass putextras with intent and trying to get the same values on textviews on nxt page

Tags: java, android, android-intent

1. here I am passing an intent in `show()` with a bundle of data from the
   database

   Mainactivity.java

   ```
   import android.app.AlertDialog; import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; 
   import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.Toast;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
       public DatabaseHelper Mydb;   
       EditText etname, etsurname, etadress,etmarks, etid, etsearch; 
       Button Add;   
       Button BView;   
       Button Update;
       Button Delete;
       Button Search;

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           Mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);//going to call constructor of database helper class where we are creating db and table

           etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_NAME);
           etsurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_SURNAME);
           etadress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ADDRESS);
           etmarks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_MARKS);
           etid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ID);


           Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ADD);
           BView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_VIEW);
           Update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_UPDATE);
           Delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_DELETE);


       }

       public void ADD(View v) {
           boolean isInserted = Mydb.insertData(etname.getText().toString(), etsurname.getText().toString(), etadress.getText().toString(), etmarks.getText().toString());

           if (isInserted == true) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Data Inserted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               etname.setText("");
               etsurname.setText("");
               etadress.setText("");
               etmarks.setText("");
           } else

               Toast.makeText(this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       public void VIEW(View v) {
           Cursor res = Mydb.getAllData();//dbhelper object to fetch data

           if (res.getCount() == 0) {
               //show messege
               Show("Error", "Nothing Found");
               return;

           }
           StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
           while (res.moveToNext()) {
               buffer.append("ID: " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
               buffer.append("Name: " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
               buffer.append("Surname: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
               buffer.append("Address: " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
               buffer.append("Marks: " + res.getString(4) + "\n\n");
           }

           //show data
           Show("Data", buffer.toString());
       }

       public void Show(String title, String Messege) {
          /* AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.setCancelable(true);

           builder.setTitle(title);
           builder.setMessage(Messege);

           builder.show();*/
           String sid=null,nam=null,addr=null,surn=null,mar=null;

           String e1= etname.getText().toString();
           etsurname.getText();
           etadress.getText();
           etmarks.getText();
           etid.getText();
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Showdb.class);

           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
           bundle.putString("sid",e1);
           bundle.putString("nam",etname.getText().toString());
   //Add the bundle to the intent
           i.putExtras(bundle);
           startActivity(i);


           // i.putExtra(sid, new String[] { etid.getText().toString(),etname.getText().toString(),etsurname.getText().toString(),etadress.getText().toString(),etmarks.getText().toString()});
       }

       public void UPDATE(View v) {
           boolean isUpdated = Mydb.UpdateData(etid.getText().toString(), etname.getText().toString(), etsurname.getText().toString(), etadress.getText().toString(), etmarks.getText().toString());

           if (isUpdated == true) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Data Updated Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else
               Toast.makeText(this, "Data Not Updated Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       public void DELETE(View v) {
           Integer deletedrows = Mydb.deleteData(etid.getText().toString());

           if (deletedrows > 0) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Data Deleted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else
               Toast.makeText(this, "Data not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }

       public void SEARCH(View v) {
           Cursor cursor = Mydb.SearchData(etsearch.getText().toString());

           while (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               String Record = (cursor.getString(0));


           }
       }
   }
   ```

   here m trying to display the buddle values as text view by accepting
   values passed through an intent. unable to display anything on
   showdb activity

   Showdb.java

   ```
   public class Showdb extends AppCompatActivity {
       public DatabaseHelper Mydb;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_showdb);


           Bundle getBundle = null;
           getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

           String name = getBundle.getString("sid");
           String id = getBundle.getString("nam");
           String Surname= getBundle.getString("surn");
           String Address = getBundle.getString("addr");
           String Marks = getBundle.getString("mar");
           TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
           TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
           TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
           TextView tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
           TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
           tv.setText(id);
           tv1.setText(name);
           tv2.setText(Surname);
           tv3.setText(Address);
           tv4.setText(Marks);


       }

   }
   ```

Comment: I don't see a question here. What problems are you having?

Comment: Is your `Showdb` activity started?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace following piece of code.

From **MainActivity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Showdb.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
        bundle.putString("sid",e1);
        bundle.putString("nam",etname.getText().toString());
//Add the bundle to the intent
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
```

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Showdb.class);
        i.putExtra("sid",e1);
        i.putExtra("nam",etname.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

From **Showdb**

```
Bundle getBundle = null;
getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    String name = getBundle.getString("sid");
    String id = getBundle.getString("nam");
```

to

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("sid"); //get sid from intent
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("nam"); //get name from intent
```